# OS X Service Packs?

Tags: macos, system-requirements

I'm trying to get the Mindstorms software on my MacBook, and this is part of the requirements:

```
Mac 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8 with the latest service packs
```

What are the service packs it is talking about? Were they on older versions of OS X, but not on the current version? I'm confused because I thought service packs were a Microsoft thing.

**EDIT:** I'm currently running 10.10.1 (Yosemite).

Comment: Lego Mindstorms? Check [bricks](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/is-the-lego-midstorms-ev3-software-compatible-with-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoever wrote the requirements probably *is* more familiar with Windows terminology. While they aren't called "service packs", every major release of OS X (such as 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8) has had multiple "minor" or "point" releases containing improvements and fixes. See [this list](http://robservatory.com/a-useless-analysis-of-os-x-release-dates/) for details of release dates. For the example given, 10.6.8, 10.7.5, and 10.8.5 would be the most-current releases of the major versions mentioned.

These minor updates have historically been made available through the Software Update item under OS X's Apple menu, and, since either 10.7 or 10.8, are now available through the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Service Pack is Microsoft naming convention for a major update pack which incorporates a plethora of minor security and other updates in one single installer.

A rough Apple equivalent are the latest Combo Updates:

[Mac OS X 10.6.8 Client Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1399/MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.8.dmg)
[Mac OS X 10.7.5 Client Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1582/MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.5.dmg)
[Mac OS X 10.8.5 Client Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1676/OSXUpdCombo10.8.5.dmg)